# How do I call getAssociatedProducts from template/catalog/product/list.phtml in magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to display details of all associated products of a grouped product on the product listing page.

I am trying to do this:

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $_associatedProducts = $_product->getAssociatedProducts(); ?> 
    <!-- SOME CODE -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but I am getting nothing in $_associatedProducts. Please suggest.

Thanks
Abhinav

Answer (score 1):

I have optimized the code to display the associated products of group product.

```
<?php
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
        // Do something with $associatedProducts
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code work for me

```
$_associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductIds($_product); 
foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_associatedProduct) {
 $_productAssociated = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_associatedProduct);
 // Do something with $_productAssociated
}
```

Thanks